# Display Customer Firstname and User Meta to New Woocomerce account email

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, woocommerce, user-data

I want to get the the new registrant first name and display it on my email template:

```
$firstname = get_user_meta($userid,'first_name',true);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($firstname);
echo '</pre>'
```

But it is not returning the value. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: apply a print_r/var_dump on $userid too and see what it returns

Comment: it returns the userid of the registrant, it returns the correct id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was how the user is created and this is my code for creating the user:

```
$user = wc_create_new_customer($email,$email,$password);
```

In order to fix that I change the code to:

```
$new_customer_data = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_new_customer_data', array(
    'user_login'  => $email,
    'user_pass' => $password  ,
    'first_name'  =>  $firstname ,
    'last_name' =>  $lastname ,
    'user_email'  =>$email ,
    'display_name'  =>  $firstname . ' ' . $lastname  ,
    'nickname'  => $firstname . ' ' . $lastname ,
    'role'    => 'customer'
) );
$user_id = wp_insert_user( $new_customer_data );
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try [**`get_userdata()`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata) wordpress function with the User ID, to get the user object. With this user object you can get all other data this way:

```
$user_data = get_userdata( $userid );
echo 'Username: ' . $user_data->user_login . '<br>';
echo 'First name: ' . $user_data->first_name . '<br>';
echo 'Last name: ' . $user_data->last_name . '<br>';
echo 'User roles: ' . implode(', ', $user_data->roles) . '<br>';
echo 'User ID: ' . $user_data->ID . '<br>';

// To look at the available User raw data:
echo '<pre>'; print_r($user_data); echo '</pre>';

// To look at the available User raw Meta data
echo '<pre>'; print_r(get_post_meta( $userid )); echo '</pre>';
```

> To get the **First name** and **last name,** your registering form need to have additionally that 2 fields

---

For other emails notification, once an order has been created one time, you can get easily from the Order ID this data:

```
// In case that you have only the $order object
if(empty($order_id)) 
    $order_id = $order->id;

$customer_id = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_customer_user', true);
$billing_first_name = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_first_name', true);
$billing_last_name = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_last_name', true);

// Displaying "First name"
echo 'First name: '. $billing_first_name;
```

Comment: but the thing here is the email is triggered on user registration not on checkout, so there is no order created yet

Comment: i did get the $user_data object but when i tried using this $user_data->first_name it doesnt return a value

Comment: [data] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 87
            [user_login] => email
            [user_pass] => $P$BrO7b5bsgMK4fjJpL1OspyPV35rBsm/
            [user_nicename] => 
            [user_email] =>emai
            [user_url] => 
            [user_registered] => 2017-03-28 07:32:37
            [user_activation_key] => 
            [user_status] => 0
            [display_name] =>

Comment: i think it should be get_user_meta($userid), first name and last name is on my registration form and input data is save via a custom function i created, registration form is a custom form

Comment: `Array
(
    [nickname] => Array
        (
            [0] => elland@follow.com.au
        )

    [first_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [last_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )
}` still returning empty values

Comment: @Elland As you see the only defined data is the email… So that's why you don't get any data for `first_name` or `last_name`, because the values are empty… If needed, contact me on _Skype_chat, my ID is `marsloic`…